# Django URL duplication Bug

Tags: django, bootstrap-4

I'm developing a little application in Django and I need to add a contact form. U know, the typical send mail form. Everything works right, but when I was testing the nav bar I notice that, when I click the same route two times the route is douplicated

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/Contacto/Contacto
```

Is really funny to see but I began to despair. My question is, is there any way to avoid this bug?

This is how I declared the path in urls.py :

```
path('Contacto/', views.contactPageRender, name="Contacto")
```

This is the function that render the .html file:

```
def contactPageRender(request):
    return render(request,"contact.html")
```

And this is the html tag that drives to the URL:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top" style="background-color: #bebebe;">
  <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a href="Contacto" class="nav-link">Contacto</a>
    </li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a bug, since the link does not start with a slash (`/`), the browser assumes that this is a *relative* path.

You should define the `href="…"` as:

```
<a href="/Contacto" class="nav-link">Contacto</a>
```

But it is better to make use of the [**`{% url … %}`** template tag [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url):

```
<a href="{% url 'Contacto' %}" class="nav-link">Contacto</a>
```

here `'Contacto'` refers to the `name=…` of the path.

Comment: Thanks!! I didn't know about this. In my Web Technologies class  just saw the way I posted in the question. Really thanks!!